# How do I open a folder from CD drive using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, directory, cd-drive

I'm trying to write a program that opens a folder from the CD disk when a button is clicked. The program will be run from a CD, and aims to open a certain folder. However, I can't use "shell "explorer...."" because the drive letter will change between different computers. Is there a way to open the folder straight from the CD in VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

It is easy if you know that your program was started from the CD.  Just read the program location back:

```
    Dim exePath As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
    Dim drive As String = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(exePath)
```

Comment: Does the 'drive' variable refer to the executed path or to the drive letter?

Comment: If the CD drive is D then drive will contain "D:\". Use Path.Combine to create the full path to the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Example, if I want execute an file: executable.exe;
In Optical drive E:\executables\executable.exe")

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim strDrives() As String

        Dim drvInof As System.IO.DriveInfo

        'Get all drives on the computer

.       strDrives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives

        'list all the drives

        For i As Int16 = 0 To strDrives.Length

            'Get drive info

            drvInof = New System.IO.DriveInfo(strDrives(i))

            'Check if it`s CDRom

            If drvInof.DriveType = IO.DriveType.CDRom Then

                'Run exe from the CDRom

                Try

                  'here we try to run from the cdrom we found the exe

                    Process.Start(drvInof.Name & "executables\executable.exe")

                Catch ex As Exception

                    'error handle if the exe is not found or anything else

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

                End Try

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> - Find all the drive letters on the
>     system.
> - For each drive
> - - if the specific folder exists open it.
> - Loop

Comment: Right, thanks for that, but can you provide the specific syntax for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This link contains some basic stuff. It should get you pointed in the right direction. Also, take keywords from the code sample and search MSDN. MSN has lots of documentation and samples that may get you to the next step.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6081470.html#

edit - try this...

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each D As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives
            If D.DriveType = DriveType.CDRom Then
                Debug.WriteLine(D.Name)
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using this code:

```
 Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

    Dim d As DriveInfo
    For Each d In allDrives
        'Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
        'Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
        If d.DriveType = DriveType.CDRom Then
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume Name: {0}", d.Name)
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", _
                    d.AvailableFreeSpace)

                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes", _
                    d.TotalFreeSpace)

                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ", _
                    d.TotalSize)
            End If
        End If

    Next
```